# Automatically add the "fill-in" value from the Choice column to the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, custom-form, choice-field

I wish Microsoft included a second checkbox for the Choice Column labeled "Capture 'Fill-in' choices" that would automatically add the user's fill-in choice to the dropdown list.

I'm using SP2013. I don't have access to Designer, or InfoPath, or SP Event Receivers, or Nintex Workflow.

I'm here fishing for a complete javascript piece of code I can add to the New/Edit forms as a script editor web part, which triggers on form closure, or when they leave the fill-in field.

If I make progress, I'll post it here too.

**Update 1:**

There appears to be some code [HERE](https://community.nintex.com/thread/17481-mutual-reset-choice-vs-fill-in-choice#comment-68969) that explains how to retrieve the value in the fill-in text box. Just need to work out how to trigger, then update the drop-down list.